# R within Rstudio cannot find rmarkdown package

Tags: r, markdown, rstudio

I am trying to use rmarkdown, within Rstudio (0.98.953) on a PC, for the first time. I have upgraded to the latest versions of R (3.1.1) and R studio. The output from sessionInfo() is provided at the end of this question.

As I understand it rmarkdown should be included within Rstudio. However, when I select to create a markdown document in Rstudio, a dialog box pops up saying additional packages need to be installed. The installation of rmarkdown always then fails, with the following message:

```
Installing package into '\\cfsk18.campus.gla.ac.uk/SSD_Home_Data_X/jm383x/My        Documents/R/win-library/3.1'
(as 'lib' is unspecified)
* installing *source* package 'rmarkdown' ...
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
*** arch - i386
Warning in library(pkg_name, lib.loc = lib, character.only = TRUE, logical.return =     TRUE) :
  there is no package called 'rmarkdown'
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
*** arch - x64
Warning in library(pkg_name, lib.loc = lib, character.only = TRUE, logical.return =     TRUE) :
  there is no package called 'rmarkdown'
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed for 'i386', 'x64'
* removing '\\cfsk18.campus.gla.ac.uk/SSD_Home_Data_X/jm383x/My Documents/R/win-    library/3.1/rmarkdown'
Warning messages:
1: running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.1/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "\\cfsk18.campus.gla.ac.uk\SSD_Home_Data_X\jm383x\My Documents\R\win-library\3.1"     "C:/PROGRA~1/RStudio/R/packages/rmarkdown_0.2.49_047a80058bb4ef0b142196013d1c4dd8870d4dd9.tar.gz"' had status 1 
2: In utils::install.packages("C:/Program     Files/RStudio/R/packages/rmarkdown_0.2.49_047a80058bb4ef0b142196013d1c4dd8870d4dd9.tar.gz",      :
  installation of package     'C:/PROGRA~1/RStudio/R/packages/rmarkdown_0.2.49_047a80058bb4ef0b142196013d1c4dd8870d4dd9.tar.gz' had non-zero exit status
```

I assume this is something to do with using a managed desktop in my place of work. However this is not usually a problem as far fewer restrictions are placed on these machines than is usually the case, and all other packages, software etc tend to work.

I have also tried installing rmarkdown directly from github. Again the installer cannot identify the package rmarkdown itself.

What is likely to be the cause of the error?

### SessionInfo output:

```
R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252        LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                            LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.1.1
```

### Attempt to install directly from github repo:

```
devtools::install_github("rstudio/rmarkdown")
Installing github repo rmarkdown/master from rstudio
Downloading master.zip from https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/archive/master.zip
Installing package from C:\Users\jm383x\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpINmLRv/master.zip
Installing rmarkdown
Installing dependencies for rmarkdown:
httpuv
Installing package into ‘\\cfsk18.campus.gla.ac.uk/SSD_Home_Data_X/jm383x/My     Documents/R/win-library/3.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.1/httpuv_1.3.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 857357 bytes (837 Kb)
opened URL
downloaded 837 Kb

package ‘httpuv’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\jm383x\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpINmLRv\downloaded_packages
"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.1/bin/x64/R" --vanilla CMD INSTALL  \
  "C:\Users\jm383x\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpINmLRv\devtoolscec10833677\rmarkdown-master"       \
  --library="\\cfsk18.campus.gla.ac.uk/SSD_Home_Data_X/jm383x/My Documents/R/win-   library/3.1" --install-tests 

* installing *source* package 'rmarkdown' ...
** R
** inst
** tests
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
*** arch - i386
    Warning in library(pkg_name, lib.loc = lib, character.only = TRUE, logical.return =     TRUE) :
      there is no package called 'rmarkdown'
    Error: loading failed
    Execution halted
    *** arch - x64
     Warning in library(pkg_name, lib.loc = lib, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE) :
  there is no package called 'rmarkdown'
    Error: loading failed
    Execution halted
    ERROR: loading failed for 'i386', 'x64'
* removing '\\cfsk18.campus.gla.ac.uk/SSD_Home_Data_X/jm383x/My Documents/R/win-      library/3.1/rmarkdown'
```

Comment: There is no `rmarkdown` package. You maybe mean `markdown`.

Comment: 'rmarkdown' is the package the latest version of Rstudio searches for automatically when I try to create a markdown document for the first time. Could this be a simple error in RStudio's code?

Comment: The `rmarkdown` package is available from github: https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown

Comment: I don't think so. Try with [this](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown)

Comment: As I said in at the end of the question I've already tried to install directly from github. The error - not being able to find the package called 'rmarkdown' - is repeated when using this approach.

Comment: I've added the results of trying to install from github directly to the bottom of the question

Answer (score 14):

Try running this code to get the latest version of the rmarkdown package, which should solve the issue:

```
install.packages("rmarkdown", repos = "https://cran.revolutionanalytics.com")
```

The issue is that the RStudio IDE looks at a static CRAN snapshot that was taken before the rmarkdown package was updated.  For more information, see this link: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rropen/Kgg8z6FF40I

Comment: Thanks-- this is by far the easiest solution.

Answer (score 2):

I wonder if the problem is the space in the path shown for the --library option to your install_github command.  I know you say you've installed packages OK before, but my setup sounds just slike yours and rmarkdown works for me.  I have RStudio 0.98.953 on Win7, which is a very locked-down corporate machine.  I've coerced it into letting me install R packages by setting the env variable R_LIBS to my network home drive.  Loading packages is slow, but I have no choice because I cannot write to the C: drive.  So, my install_github command has --library="H:/Rlib".  Your path has "My Documents" embedded in it.  I'm not positive that's the problem, but my github installation of "rstudio/rmarkdown" did succeed.  When I do File -> New File -> R Markdown, followed by a press of the "Knit  HTML" button, that also completes successfully.

The RStudio github page https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown#installation makes it sound like manual installation of rmarkdown in RStudio isn't required, but I did it anyway because I don't always use R through RStudio.  Sorry, but I didn't test RStudio by making a new R Markdown file before I manually installed the package.

The RStudio blog post http://blog.rstudio.org/2014/06/18/r-markdown-v2/ says clearly that the rmarkdown package is intended to replace the previous markdown package.  The rmarkdown package does not yet appear to be on CRAN, so install_github is necessary.

Comment: Thanks. Now trying from the home PC and rmarkdown installs without any problem. The issue might be that the network space which is the default location is more limited than the hard disk, so might be running out of space part way through the installation. I'll first try clearing the network space, then if that doesn't work change R_LIBS, then if that doesn't work also uninstall and reinstall r and rstudio. Hopefully I should get there. Thanks.

Comment: I was talking about a space character in the library path, not running out of storage space on the specified drive.  Could be running out of space, I suppose. Also, maybe try using a drive letter for the library location, rather than the \\servername\path\to\folder syntax.  I've seen R on Windows get confused and try to create a new local folder at C:\servername\path\to\folder instead of going out to the server.

Comment: One last thought, for users of corporate lockdown PCs.  On my work Win7 PC, I can't right-click on Computer and change environment variables.  (In WinXP, it was My Computer I think.)  But I can do it through the Start menu's Search field.  So a search for "environment", and it'll give you a result to click on "Edit environment variables for your account".  That should let you set the R_LIBS variable even w/o admin privileges.

Comment: You can also use the `setx PATH %PATH%;C:\somepath` syntax in a non-privileged admin to change the PATH environment variable at the user level. More info available in [this technet article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755104.aspx). Note that you if you're in a cmd prompt, you will need to relaunch it in order to reload the environment variables.

Answer (score 2):

The best that worked for me is to quit Rstuido, then install rmarkdown package in the base R (not any IDE) and restarting Rstudio.

I am on Windows 10, R 3.3.1, Rstudio Version 0.99.903